# Where to set self from this, inside a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've noticed inside the instance of my object, if I have a jQuery click handler etc. the `this` keyword gets overwritten therefore I have to set a `self` property outside the scope and access that.

My questions are:

- **Should I set self, in the body of my object, or in each method.** *Is
  there a difference?*
- **Does self in this case point to the instance and not the class?**

Thanks!

```
var ExampleVM = function () {
        var self1 = this;
        this.toggleIsSlidedOut = function () {
            var self2 = this;
            this.$con.animate({
                right: '+=' + posX + 'px'
            }, 400, function () {
                selfx.isSlidedOut(!this.isSlidedOut());
            });
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I set self, in the body of my object, or in each method. Is there a difference?

Since the comment below clarified that this is in regards to the `.animate()` callback: ([previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18690029/4))

The difference between `self1` and `self2` is mostly a matter of style. Going with `self1`, you only need to define it once. But, `self2` will keep the declaration closer to where it's used.

But, either way, it'll work so long as you use `self` (or `self1`, etc.) for both method calls:

```
self.isSlidedOut(!self.isSlidedOut());
```

As `this` will refer to the `Element` that was animated.

Note: if the focus was on `toggleIsSlidedOut`, as I first though, then it could make a difference. Then it depends on whether you wanted that method effectively bound to the instance (`self1`) or able to interact with other contexts (`self2`).

---

> Does self in this case point to the instance and not the class?

It should point to the instance. Within any `function`, it's rare for `this` to refer to the `function` that's being called.

If you need a reference, you can use its name any properties holding it:

```
this.toggleIsSlidedOut = function actualFunctionName() {
    console.log(actualFunctionName); // function ...

    // ...
};
```

Though, if you should ever happen to forget to use `new` with `ExampleVM`, `this` can refer to the "*global*" object (`window` in browsers) or be `undefined`.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I meant inside the animate function.this.toggleIsSlidedOut is not a callback

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, good answer! To any would-be contributors, I wonder if "will keep the declaration closer to where it's used." has any potential implications